# Can we initialize an object with the help of constructor of another class?

Tags: java, oop

Can we initialize an object with the help of constructor of another class?

```
class1 object = new class2();
```

Comment: Yes. Better to pick a single language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as `class2` extends (or implements in case of an interface) `class1` that is fine. For example, `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();`

To be clear, you are creating an instance of `class2` (or `ArrayList` from my example). It just so happens that you have declared your variable to be of type `class1` (or `List`).

Comment: This is useful for when you need some high-level behaviour, but don't care about the implementation details. For instance, your API may expose a function that takes a `Map` as an argument, but you don't care whether the argument is a `HashMap` or a `TreeMap`. It's good practice to declare your types as generic as possible, since this helps with decoupling, code readability and maintenance (refactoring) all in one.

Comment: Speaking for Java: "extends" => "extends or implements"

Answer (score 2):

The only way for this to work in C++

```
class1 object1 = new class2();
```

would be to have an implicit conversion between `class2*` and `class1`. This can be achieved with a converting constructor:

```
struct class1
{
  class1(const class2*);
};
```

Whether this constitutes using a constructor of a class to "help" construct an object of a different one depends on what you mean by helping to construct.

If you meant

```
class1 object1 = class2();
```

then the converting constructor would need to take a `class2` by value or reference. For example,

```
struct class1
{
  class1(const class2&);
};
```

There is no need for an *is-a* relationship between the types.

Answer (score 1):

Only speaking for C++: It's possible but the classes require a polymorphic "is a" relation (public inheritance in C++). For example:

```
class class1 { };
class class2 : public class1
{
    class2(int) {}
};


class1* object1 = new class2(42); // A pointer is needed (in C++)
delete object1;

// better would be:
std::unique_ptr<class1> object1(new class2(42));
```

Edit:
Meanwhile the thread opener removed the C++-Tag, so my answer doens't have any relevance anymore.

Comment: The classes do not require an "is-a" relationship, just a converting constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible only if class2 s a subclass of class1.
This is called polymorphism.

```
class Class1{
 /*
  *
  *
  body of class1
  *
  */
 }


class Class2 extends Class1{
 /*
  *
  *
  body of class2
  *
  */
 }
```

Then you can declare

Class1 object1 = new Class2();

Hope this helped..

Answer (score 0):

```
class class1{}
class class2 extends class1{}
```

If you have a parent child relationship in class hierarchy then it is not a problem at all.
Then 
 `class1 object1 = new class2();` is valid 
actually what is happening inside is you are having an class2 object but that is referenced by an class1 variable.

but if you have like

```
class class1{}
class class2{}
```

Then this is not working